# Binding to DataModel in MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have done the intro tutorial online and it works.  My question is how does Mvvmcross know which View to associate with the ViewModel?  There is nothing I can see in the code where they reference each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode is by naming convention.
If your view is called "AwesomeView", Mvx will assign "AwesomeViewModel" to it at the app initialization.

When your view is instantiated, Mvx will "inject" the dependency (ViewModel) into your view as a binding context

So the convention to look up the view model is [ViewName]Model
If I´m correct this works using reflection

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  I had spent all day trying to figure it.  Who knew it was that simple!

Comment: That´s right. Nothing makes sense if you don´t know about the convention.